# Android : Face Detection on Mjpeg Stream from IP Camera

Tags: android, face-detection, ip-camera

I am using Simplemjpegview (https://bitbucket.org/neuralassembly/simplemjpegview) in my android project to display video stream from an ip camera. I want to implement face detection on that displayed stream. Any help is appreciated ...

Comment: hey, you found any solution?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

[OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html#face-recognition) has general purpose facial recognition for Android and there are many tutorials online for implementing in facial recognition in video streams using OpenCV. [Here's one](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html).

Something like this is probably the quickest method for your use case.

I bet you can implement a virtual camera for the stream in order to use the built-in facial recognition features if you're targeting newer android, 4.1+ I think. But this seems like overkill.